# chromatic equivalence implies isomorphism

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

I'm currently working on the following problems:

> (a) Show that if $G$ has the same chromatic polynomial as $K_n$ then $G \cong K_n$.

> (b) Show that if $G$ has the same chromatic polynomial as $K_{n,n}$ then $G \cong K_{n,n}$.

My approach for (a) was: Note that $P_{K_n}(x)=x(x-1)(x-2)...(x-(n-1))$.
Now suppose we have a graph $G$ with this chromatic polynomial. Then we have a choice of $x$ colours for the first vertex. For the second vertex we have a choice of $x-1$ colours, which means it is connected to the first vertex. For the third vertex we have a choice of $x-2$ vertices, which means it has to be connected to the previous two vertices. Continue this until we reach the last, i.e. the $n$-th vertex. We have a choice of $x-(n-1)$ colours which means our vertex is connected to all other vertices, who all have distinct colours. So since every vertex is connected to all previous vertices, $G$ is the complete graph.

Now for (b) I'm a little more stuck. I struggle to find the chromatic polynomial and then also do stuff with it. I think the following Claim might help me: $G$ is bipartite $\iff$ $P_G(x)$ not divisible by $(x-2)$. But I'm not sure how to prove this claim. I suppose if I had that claim, I need to prove that if we have two bipartite chromatically equivalent graphs, they are isomorphic. I would really appreciate help! Thank you!

(To delete: please help me with the formating, would love to have the question in one indent, but two paragraphs, don't know how to do that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) Indeed, if $G$ has the same chromatic polynomial as $K_n$, then $n-1$ is a root of $P_G(x)$, meaning that $G$ is not $n-1$ colourable, so by Brooks' theroem, it is either an odd cycle or $K_n$ itself. Now you can easily conclude that $G$ is not an odd cycle for $n > 3$.

Hint for b): Since $G$ has the same chromatic polynomial as $K_{n,n}$, and $K_{n,n}$ is $2$-colourable, $2$ is not a root of $P_G(x)$. So $G$ is $2$-colourable, hence bipartite. Looking at the leading term and second leading term of both chromatic polynomials, we deduce that $V(G) = V(K_{n,n}) = 2n$ and $E(G) = E(K_{n,n}) = n^2$.

Write $G = (A,B)$. So $G$ is a bipartite graph, with $|A| + |B| = 2n$, and $E(G) = n^2$. Use the AM-GM inequality to deduce that $|A| = |B| = n$ (check when equality holds in AM-GM). Once you have this, for $E(G) = n^2$, every vertex in $A$ must be incident to every vertex in $B$, giving $G \cong K_{n,n}$.